# Using content: " "; in SASS (not scss)

Tags: html, css, compiler-errors, sass

This must be a very simple question for experienced SASS coders, I'm starting to work with it instead of using SCSS, 
All i want to know is how to make pseudo-elements with a "blank" content element, in order to make them work (appear on DOM) 
I'll write it in scss:

```
#element {
    &:before {
        content:'';
    }
}
```

This is what i want to accomplish in SASS, it won't compile if i write it like this:

```
#element
    &:before
        content:''
```

it seems to be expecting a value of content, i use this in order to make decorative pseudo-elements, like borders,lines, or elements with another bg, a lot of stuff like:

```
#element {
    &:before {
        content:'';
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: black;
    }
}
```

This is just an example, i know the syntax for css and scss, but for sass it just won't compile.

Comment: Did SO change the format of your Sass, or did you write it without line breaks?

Comment: And when you say "it just won't compile," what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you haven't space between `content:` and quotes. I get an error without space (SASS expect a pseudo-class or pseudo-element) but works fine with space:

```
#element
  &:before 
    content: ''
```

Comment: Nice, I can reproduce this. Assuming OP is using line breaks, this is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

```
element
  &:before
    content: ""
```

and

```
element2
  &:before
    content: ''
```

and

```
element3:before
  content: ""
```

and

```
element4:before
  content: ''
```

seem to work fine for me in all Sass compilers supported by SassMeister (LibSass 3.3.6, Sass 4.0.0.alpha.1, Sass 3.4.21, Sass 3.3.14). Here's a working gist: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/0249fb7d41b10250bbcbcf336ef3d4f5 (change the compiler under the Options menu; note the libsass comment is being added by SassMeister, I can't seem to remove it)

Comment: Hello, I'm using gulp-sass to compile it, would that be the issue?

Comment: Ok I tested `gulp-sass`, and it works for me. You haven't said if you're writing it on one line (your example) or multiple lines, but if it's multiple lines and the file has the `.sass` extension it sounds like the problem must be somewhere else